# If $A'$ and $B'$ have the same cardinality, as do $A\subseteq A'$ and $B\subseteq B'$, are $A'\setminus A$ and $B'\setminus B$ equipotent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $A\subset A'$, $B\subset B'$, if $\operatorname{card}(A)=\operatorname{card}(B)$ and $\operatorname{card}(A')=\operatorname{card}(B')$, why is it that $\operatorname{card}(A'\backslash A)=\operatorname{card}(B'\backslash B)$ ?

Comment: It isn't. Let $A=A'=\mathbb{N} = B$ and $B'=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Teddy: If you're gonna edit old posts, might as well do it right. `\operatorname` also produces the correct spacing that `\text` or `\mathrm` or whatever won't. (And giving better titles would also be appropriate for cases like this one.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, will remember that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You made the title inconsistent with the post itself: one declares $A\subseteq A'$, the other one $A'\subseteq A$.

Comment: @CiaPan: You can also fix obvious typos yourself, you know.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I typed up \text{card}(A) and \operatorname{card}(A) and they look identical. I even tried it with $A'$ inside the brackets to see if there are any kerning issues, still identical. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Teddy: $\rm\LaTeX$-education opportunities.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know. But that was not _obvious_ to me, which version was correct.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Verify, the $\LaTeX$ gods favour me today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. Consider $A'=B'=\mathbb N$, $A=\{x\in\mathbb N:x\ge3\}$, $B=\{x\in\mathbb N:x\ge9\}$.

Comment: Set theory can be counter-intuitive sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider real interval $A=[0,2]$ of cardinality $\mathfrak C$.

We'll subtract four different intervals, non-degenerate hence each equipollent to $A$, and get distinct cardinalities of resulting sets:

$A \setminus [0,2] = \{\}$ – empty set, cardinality $0$.

$A \setminus [0,2) = \{ 2 \}$ – a singleton, cardinality $1$.

$A \setminus (0,2) = \{ 0, 2 \}$ – two-item set, cardinality $2$.

$A \setminus [1,2] = [0,1)$ – interval, cardinality $\mathfrak C$.